# Creating and serving an image using AppEngine

Tags: image, google-app-engine

In Google AppEngine I want to transform a boolean[] into an image then serve the image.  I want the boolean[] to be transformed to black and white pixels.  I can see that AppEngine provides

```
import com.google.appengine.api.images.Image;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesService;
import com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceFactory;

// ...
byte[] imageData;  // ...   
ImagesService imagesService = ImagesServiceFactory.getImagesService();    
Image image = ImagesServiceFactory.makeImage(imageData);
```

but I don't know what the format of the `byte[] imageData` should be, i.e., how to transform the `boolean[]` to `byte[]`

And once I have this image, how can the client get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Image service API accepts data in any of the supported image file formats.  According to [this page](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/images/overview.html), these formats include "JPEG, PNG, WEBP, GIF (including animated GIF), BMP, TIFF and ICO".  The Image service does not provide a way to create new image data from scratch.  But you can use a graphics library to produce the image in one of the accepted data formats, then use the service to convert it to another format, or transform it.  Of course, depending on the graphics library, you may be able to get the final image directly from the library, and not use the service.

To serve an image, just set the appropriate `Content-Type` header for the data format you're using, then write the bytes of the image data to the response's output stream:

```
// byte[] pngData = ...
resp.addHeader("Content-Type", "image/png");
resp.getOutputStream().write(pngData);
```

If you want to try generating the image data without a library, [the BMP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) might be easiest.  You can use the Images service to convert this to PNG.

Comment: thanks.  The problem is the graphics library, is one available that will work in App Engine?

Comment: Dan Sanderson is correct.  [Here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip60.html?page=2)  is some code to generate a BMP formatted byte array from a raw pixel array.  It still has some references to classes that aren't available to AppEngine, but they can be removed.